# How can I include selenium nunit test cases in tfs 2013 continuous build integration

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-2013, nunit

How can I include selenium nunit test cases in tfs 2013 CI build definition and view the results? When I try to run the test cases using VS runner. I get:

> NUnit.Core.UnsupportedFrameworkException.

Comment: Hi Patrick, please provide more details. Screenshots, logs, etc.

Comment: Yes... specifically, what version of hte nunit framework, what version of the NUnit VS adapter (if using)